# Retrieve each site's favicon image with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a JavaScript function to retrieve each favicon from a site url, I know the favicon can be retrieved from `urlsite/favicon.ico` but not all sites are like that.

Google has an API like: https://t0.gstatic.com/faviconV2?client=SOCIAL&type=FAVICON&fallback_opts=TYPE,SIZE,URL&url=https://stackoverflow.com/&size=64

Can I make it in JavaScript?  (without APIs)

Comment: In node? In the browser? Regardless, there's probably too much here to cover in a single question

Comment: The simple answer to your question is **no**. JavaScript alone is not capable of pulling information from most sites around the internet typically due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Could you do it without Google's API? ***Yes***. But you will pretty much always need some sort of server component to make it work, not client-side JavaScript by itself.